# Does there exist QFT which do not yield infinities?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, singularities, regularization

Does there exist a "simple", "polynomial-like" quantum field theory (unrealistic, not describing our world, in any spacetime dimension $d$) which does not yield infinities in computations as QED does?

I ask this question because I red it is believed that QED is an effective theory. But I ask myself if this theory can even be extended by further expressions, say, such that the problems with infinities vanish. Regardless whether the theory is realistic.

I know that by dimensional regularization one can introduce a new parameter $d$, the dimension,  and define a new  QED dependent also on $d$ and for $5 > d > 4$ the infinities disappear in computations (perturbation theory), but this theory is then more "analytic", as it can be expressed by the $\Gamma$-function.

Comment: specifically *which* infinity do you mean here? The Landau pole of QED or the more general "infinities" that appear in the usual formulation of renormalization?

Comment: I think I mean renormalization. Overall I mean infinities that come out by concrete computations ("self-loops" diagrams).

Comment: Best toy is N=4 super Yang-Mills... have you studied it in class?

Comment: Where does the $4<d<5$ bound come from? Which reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic, I am not complete sure, I have several textbooks. Typically my main reference is Ryder, but also Weinberg, various pdf files, newly Peskin& Schroeder, internet... , but I remember I red something like "divergence at $Z$ for extended theory (dimensional regularization)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all formulations of QFT encounter "infinities" during renormalization.

For instance the mathematically rigorous formulation of [causal perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_perturbation_theory) due to Epstein and Glaser does not produce infinities and explains renormalization in terms of the difficulty to explain what is rigorously meant by terms like $\phi(x)^4$ in QFT, since quantum fields are operator-valued distributions and distributions do not carry a universal notion of multiplication at a point. However, Epstein-Glaser renormalization depends causality constraints equivalent to the Wightman axioms, and so the problem reduces to showing that actual QFTs obey the Wightman axioms.

Due to the [constructive QFT program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_quantum_field_theory) pioneered by Glimm and Jaffe, we know a lot of 2d and 3d theories, for example all theories of a scalar field in 2d with arbitrary polynomial interaction terms, that are well-defined mathematically to the degree the Wightman axioms (or their siblings, the Osterwalder-Schrader axioms) require. Glimm and Jaffe also have a formulation of renormalization in their approach where renormalization does not involve writing down quantities that are divergent but treating them as "infinite numbers" that can be absorbed by counterterms or whatever.

So there exist plenty of QFTs where we can describe renormalization without unsettling "infinities", even though the usual approach to renormalization of course still produces divergent integrals in these theories. The problem is not that we would need to modify the QFT as a physical theory to get rid of the infinities, we need to change the mathematical structure we're using to *describe* the QFT. The predictions of the approaches "with" and "without" infinities for the renormalized scattering amplitudes are the same in the end.

The problem of establishing such a rigorous model for a realistic QFT - such as the Standard Model in 4d - is the [Yang-Mills millenium problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap).

Comment: Thanks, but isn't renormalization itself the answer cure for infinities?

Comment: @hansel That we usually *introduce* renormalization to "cure infinities" in the non-rigorous approach does not mean the concept is intrinsically tied to any infinities (rigorously really: divergences).

Comment: "Causal Perturbation Theory", i.e. Epstein-Glaser Renormalization doesn't get rid of infinities, but just calls then by a different name; and the bottom line is you still have the counter-term ambiguity associated with infinity subtraction of other methods. EG is, itself, just another renormalization method - essentially equivalent to what's known as Differential Renormalization. That's been known for a quarter century now. Here's one (of many) reviews that gets to the gist of the matter. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/32/11/015

Comment: Here's another review on the matter, discussing the connection between Epstein-Glaser and Differential Renormalization; more recent. I think you'll like this one. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321314002375